# FTP UPLOAD to AS/400 from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp, ibm-midrange

I am attempting to perform a FTP Put function to an AS/400 IBM Mainframe with VB.NET.  I am able to upload a file however, I need to be able to capture each output response from the mainframe for logging purposes.  In short capture what prints out on the cmd screen if I were to perform the FTP manually.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which API/Library are you using to issue the FTP session?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the library you are using, you should be able to get some kind of response object or string from the FTP server for each command you submit. You can then parse these responses and dump them into a file/destination/source of your choosing.

EDIT: Since you're using the FTPWebRequest/Response library, you'll want to have your FTPWebRequest object dump its results into the FTPWebResponse object and then read the entire stream with code something like this:

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(serverUri), FtpWebRequest)
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory

Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

Dim responseStream As Stream = Nothing
Dim readStream As StreamReader = Nothing

Try
    responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    readStream = New StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

    If readStream IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd())
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("List status: " & response.StatusDescription)

Finally

    If readStream IsNot Nothing Then
        readStream.Close()
    End If

    If response IsNot Nothing Then
       response.Close()
    End If
End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

You should be able to tailor this code to your own in order to retrieve the response details you need.

Comment: I found the code from the url http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/b4b2e05c-625b-466b-9a11-6173f17187b4/ under the date/time posted of Friday, September 29, 2006 8:47 AM and posted by Limason.  If there is a better way, please let me know.